# Why does this expression involving HypergeometricU and $MinPrecision crash?

Tags: bugs, crash, arbitrary-precision

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.0**

---

Can somebody help me understand why the following code snippet cause the Mathematica kernel to crash (without producing any further error messages)?

```
Block[
 {
  $MinPrecision = 100,
  x = 1.`100 + 10^-55
  },
 HypergeometricU[1 - I - x, -1.`100 - I, - I]
 ]
```

I have tested on versions 8, 10.2 and 10.4 (all under Windows) and all produce a crash.

Update:
Further testing reveals that it also crashes under Linux in version 10.2, but not in version 9.0 interestingly.

Comment: It seems fine in 11.0.  Has anyone else tested it beyond 10.4?

Comment: Crashes on v10.0.1 on Mac OS 10.10.5.

Comment: Crashes on `"10.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)"` but works fine on `"11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"`.

Comment: Good to hear that it appears to not crash in 11. (That may be a reason to update my version). Just to be curious, does evaluating the expression in 11 produce any error messages?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug that has been fixed as of version 11.0.0.

```
Block[{$MinPrecision = 100, x = 1.`100 + 10^-55}, 
   HypergeometricU[1 - I - x, -1.`100 - I, -I]
]

(* 1.4703996843978260642319172877785030186700690884225572679580049005362760\
      98966709453876693385224422951 + 
   0.9303843021479835966173586034054454558900219796814908122580900574660\
      628685975476554176187307410527158 I *)
```